# Did Gandhi support homeopathy?

Tags: quotes, homeopathy, mahatma-gandhi

Sites like [this one](http://www.homeopathic.com/Articles/Media_reports/Quotes_in_Support_of_Homeopathy.html) claim Gandhi can be quoted to be in support of homeopathy:

> ***Mahatma Gandhi***
>   Homeopathy cures a greater percentage of cases than any other method of treatment. Homeopathy is the latest and refined method of treating patients economically and non-violently.

On a Dutch site this claim was [also made](http://www.wanttoknow.nl/gezondheid/homeopathie/homeopathie-bewijs-nu-uit-laboratoria/?fb_action_ids=522467624547375&fb_action_types=og.recommends&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map=%5B736588229713791%5D&action_type_map=%5B%22og.recommends%22%5D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D) (in fact the trigger for my search). Though not all too hard to believe, I still remained sceptical, trying to find a notable source for quotes like this.

I searched and found [other sceptical folk](http://www.gandhitopia.org/forum/topics/ganhdi-quote-on-homeopathy), more pro-homeopathy sites repeating said- and other quotes (e.g. [[1]](http://homeopathyplus.com.au/mohandas-karamchand-gandhi-loved-homeopathy/), [[2]](http://aurumproject.org.au/343/)), but no source of note that has above-mentioned quote too.

I did find in [this other question about Gandhi](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17806/did-gandhi-express-admiration-for-hitler-early-in-ww2) a link to [Wikiquote on Gandhi](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi), but that page does *not* contain the word "homeopathy" (not even in the "disputed" section).

Is there a notable, non-homeopathy-related source with with Gandhi quoted as supporting homeopathy, specifically mentioned quote?

Comment: How would homeopathy be "non violent"? Or, better, how would medicin be violent?

Comment: @nico vaccination is pretty violent ;) https://mobile.twitter.com/littlepowder/status/605171416023986176

Comment: @nico Many medical interventions are purely surgical. If surgery is not violent, I'm not sure what is.

Comment: Related: [Did Gandhi call vaccination a barbarous practice?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/26525)

Answer (score 12):

It was me who asked the question on the Gandhitopia forum that you found. I have also been unable to find a source for the quote the homeopaths attribute to Gandhi.

However, as you could see, I found those quotes from his letters recorded in what appears to be a reliable source (http://www.gandhiserve.org/), but they tend to indicate he was not a fan (the later quotes are first):

> 14.10.1941 I have little faith in homeopathy and yet a homeopath a crank like myself is here and treating some patients.
>
> 11.07.1940 (1) Disapproves his asking money from public Fund. (2) One needs less money if he keeps himself physically fit. Says he (G) has arranged for his Homeopathy treatment at Delhi. Hopes his total recivery.
>
> 04.04.1933 Though I have no faith in Homeopathy you may introduce the treatment after consulting the people there:
>
> 28.04.1933 Gandhiji asserts that personally he would prefer Homeopathy to Allopathy any day. As such himself does not mind his trying it after due discussion with Narandas.
>
> 16.04.1933 I have not much faith homeopathy.

For a few of these, it's difficult to know what his tone was and whether he was being sarcastic or flippant. Also, the longer quote looks like a summary of a letter, so not exactly what Gandhi wrote.

Unfortunately, no one else there replied and I have not been able to find out any more. So, as far as I'm aware, the only sources we have seem to indicate overall that Gandhi was *not* a homeopathy believer. I suspect the homeopaths' quote is fantasy.

Answer (score 6):

I found this excellent summary of one person's investigation into the "Gandhi supported homeopathy" claim. It appears to be totally bogus.

http://evidenceplease.net/tag/gandhi-homeopathy-quote/

Nevertheless, Gandhi had some pretty amazing ideas about healthcare. The pro-homeopathy myth might have started because he was a BIG supporter of water-cures. Specifically, he thought diseases are caused by impurities in the bowels and that these impurities can be removed by application of a cold-water enema.

Given the penchant for homeopaths to latch onto anything that sounds even vaguely similar to homeopathy to be evidence for homeopathy, I can see how "water-cure enema" got modified to "homeopathy" by cranks and taken as gospel by the rest.

You can read his full 1921 Guide to Health here. I particularly recommend the section on smallpox (page 104 onwards) where he quickly demonstrates his complete lack of knowledge of the causes of disease and goes on to make clear that his views are coloured by his religion.

http://www.gutenberg.org/files/40373/40373-h/40373-h.htm