# Have many Falun Gong practitioners forgone medical treatment and died of treatable causes as a result?

Tags: religion, public-health

The Chinese government is notably opposed to [Falun Gong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falun_Gong). In 1999, they were [quoted in the Sun Sentinel](https://web.archive.org/web/20150430091841/http://articles.sun-sentinel.com/1999-11-05/news/9911041104_1_falun-gong-china-s-harsh-crackdown-tiananmen-square):

> the government charged that Falun Gong was responsible for the deaths of 1,400 people -- many of whom died because they had stopped taking medication. In the past, Falun Gong's founder, Li Hongzhi, has admonished his followers to forgo traditional treatments for disease, arguing that true practitioners did not need drugs.

Do many Falun Gong practitioners eschew traditional medical treatments, and has that led to many deaths?

The same question [on Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-evidence-that-Falun-Gong-teaches-that-you-should-not-seek-professional-medical-treatment).

Comment: @Oddthinking thanks for all your editing effort, I will continue learning and trying to make better posts in the future. Cheers.

Comment: Good things about Oddthinking's edit include: a) referencing a newspaper (a newspaper is relatively 'notable'); b) including in the question a direct quote some specific sentence[s] from the referenced source; c) adding a question which asks, only, "Is the claim, which is quoted above, true?"

Comment: @ChrisW I agree the edit is for the better. Note: I did a) and part of b) after his request. c) is not entirely direct, as the newspaper claim was about those exact 1400 people, and we have extended it to practitioners in general. But it does ask what I really wanted to know, and we sense that this is what that claim to implies of course :-) (I wish I had found a more generic claim by the Chinese government).

Comment: What Li Hongzhi said sounds like what Gandhi said according to another post here.

Comment: @GEdgar although I'm not sure if it's a valid argument, I'd love to see that reference if you can find it :-)

Comment: Died early is something that is usually a bit vague and hard to pin down. Maybe "died of treatable causes" would be a better wording?

Comment: @rjzii updated as you proposed.

Comment: Re. 'what Gandhi said' I think that @GEdgar is talking about [this answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/26530/2703).