# Did "The Boy in Striped Pyjamas" have this quote, which has been compared to Trump's slogan?

Tags: quotes, movies

Did the movies "The Boy in Striped Pyjamas" have dialogue with the following subtitle, which has been compared to Trump's slogan "Make America Great Again"?

> He's [Hitler] making the country great again

[Example tweet](https://twitter.com/feminizza/status/712359856171327488)

Comment: Just for context: The slogan is older than the movie. For example, Reagan used a [similar slogan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_America_Great_Again) in the 80s.

Comment: It's such a generic quote I wouldn't be surprised if you can find it going back to comments about Roman senators.

Comment: I don't think this is notable. You're asking whether a line appeared in a movie. You have a picture of that line subtitled in that movie. What kind of evidence would convince you? Someone else taking a picture of that scene in that movie with subtitles on?

Comment: At the very least this sentiment is sixty years old: http://www.margaretthatcher.org/document/100858

Comment: @Dawn it makes the title less "subjective", but also less informative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is in the movie. You can see it in the [subtitle file](http://www.yifysubtitles.com/subtitle/the-boy-in-the-striped-pyjamas-english-yify-34291.zip):

```
495
00:54:08,880 --> 00:54:11,075
It's only horrible for them, Bruno.

496
00:54:11,120 --> 00:54:13,554
We should be proud of Dad,
now more than ever before.

497
00:54:13,600 --> 00:54:16,068
He's making the country great again.
```

Although, "he" refers to Bruno and Gretel's father, Ralf.

Comment: So, it's in the movie.  Is it in the book?

Comment: @GEdgar [It isn't](https://books.google.com/books?id=yK7jrmsqJ20C&q="great+again")

Comment: And so what if the line is in that movie?  I would bet that each of those lines (absent the name) appears in numerous books and movies, and has been used uncounted times in speech.  There are only so many words in the English language, and only a limited way to string them together to express a particular idea.  How many movies do you suppose contain a line like "I love you"?

Comment: @jamesqf It's kind of like whether Gandhi supported homeopathy - it's not terribly relevant, but it'd be convenient if the quotation were false (and it turns out the quote is partially false). http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/did-gandhi-support-homeopathy#comment84104_22085

Comment: @Dawn: But the implication here seems to be that Trump (or someone in his campaign) deliberately plagarized the line from the movie, maybe because they couldn't come up with a slogan on their own.  Which rather begs the question of whether ANY mainstream candidate in the last - oh, 50 years at least - has actually said ANYTHING original.

Comment: @jamesqf No, the implication here (here being the tweet which is the basis for notability, and also maybe the question itself) is that `Trump == Hitler` based on similarity between Trump's slogan and a line in a movie (allegedly, though per this answer incorrectly) talking about Hitler.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the implication is because we don't debunk implied claims or motivations behind claims. The only thing that matters for this site's purposes is the evidence behind the claim that the quoted line is in the movie.

Comment: @Dawn: Who exactly are you calling "we" here?  I took it for granted that the line is in the movie, since verification would be trivial, and the bare fact of interest only to collectors of movie trivia.

Comment: @jamesqf "we" means skeptics.se users. See [this meta post](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3350/handling-claims-that-are-implied-rather-than-explicit): "*claims need to be explicit*", "*it is possible the claim being asked about is only being inferred only the asker. I believe that rationale can be extended to any implied claim.*" The fact that you took the claim's truth for granted doesn't really affect this question or answer.